# How to return a value for a function in TI-89?

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

This is my function to calculate the gcd of two numbers `a` and `b`. When I use Prgm and EndPrgm, it worked fine. However, it kept popping up an error message say "Invalid in a function or current expression" when creating a function :(. Any idea?

```
gcd(a, b )
Func 
 If a>b Then
  a->t
  b->a
  t->b
 EndIf

 While b#0
  a->t
  b->a
  mod(t, b)->b 
 EndWhile
 Return a
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it solved by create a local copy of parameters:

```
Local x, y  
a->x  
b->y
```